# Accessing ZF2 created multiple select box using javascript

Tags: javascript, zend-framework2, zend-form, multiple-select

I have created a multiple select box on a form object using zend framework 2:

```
$contacts = new Element\Select('contacts');
$contacts->setLabel('All Contacts')
         ->setAttribute('name', 'contacts')
         ->setAttribute('multiple', 'multiple')
         ->setAttribute('size', 10)
         ->setOptions(array('options' => $users));
```

I would like to execute some javascript when a button on the form is pressed:

```
$moveAllRight = new Element\Button('moveAllRight');
$moveAllRight->setLabel('Move All ->')
         ->setAttribute('value', 'Move All ->')
         ->setAttribute('onClick', 'moveAll(this.form.contacts,this.form.newContacts)');
```

Unfortunately, when the page is created the name of the multiple select element is appended with []:

```
<select name="contacts[]" multiple="multiple" size="10">
```

I have tried changing the names within the js function call:

```
->setAttribute('onClick', 'moveAll(this.form.contacts[],this.form.newContacts[])');
```

but I'm am still not having any luck getting it to work. If I remove the multiple option from the select box it works, but I would like to use the multiple select box if at all possible. Is there anyway to make this work?s

Answer (score 0):

I realized that form elements can also be referred to by id as well. I set an id attribute with the same value as the name I was trying to use:

```
$contacts = new Element\Select('contacts');
$contacts->setLabel('All Contacts')
         ->setAttribute('id', 'contacts')
         ->setAttribute('multiple', 'multiple')
         ->setAttribute('size', 10)
         ->setOptions(array('options' => $users));
```

The element is created on the page:

```
<select name="contacts[]" id="contacts" multiple="multiple" size="10">
```

and I can now reference it like I originally wanted to:

```
->setAttribute('onClick', 'moveAll(this.form.contacts,this.form.newContacts)');
```